# I have a weight painting issue

Tags: weight-painting, tracking, movie-clip-editor

i need help  whenever i adjust the weight of bone 39 it increases/decreases the weight of some other bone eg bone 35, and if i adjust the weight of bone 35 it does the same for bone 39. this issue is also there with other bones too please help. I even tried parenting to empty groups and tried manuel painting

Comment: Hello, on the top right of your 3D view > Options, is Auto Normalize enabled?

Comment: I agree with moonboots. Check that. Aside from that, for future reference, please don’t use emoji‘s and repeatedly “please help“ in your question: By coming to the site, you already asking for help, and by looking at the question, we are implying that we want to help you.